# I need to display 3 unique products in each div

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to display 3 unique products in each div, like this: [Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LzuE.png)

How can I get the different products in one loop? At present in the below code, I'm getting the same product 3 times.

```
<?php
    foreach ($rows as $display) {
?>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
             <div class="section-title">
                 <div class="pull-right pr-icon">
                      <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> Top Suppliers 
                 </div>
                 <div class="main-title">
                      <b>  Selected Products</b>
                 </div>
                 <div class="sub-title">
                     Source the latest items
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                      <img src="<?php echo 'data:image;base64,'.$display->image; ?>" class="img-responsive image product-item" />
                      <div class="product-description">
                         <p class="text-center"><?php echo $display->name; ?></p>
                         <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/itemcontroller/itemFetch?id=<?php echo $display->name; ?>"><p class="desc-btn">VIEW</p></a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div> 
         </div>  
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

From controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $data['rows']=$this->homemodel->fetchData();
    $this->load->view('home',$data);
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
}
```

Model code:

```
<?php

class homemodel extends CI model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function fetchData()
    {
        $query=$this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('display');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: what you have did is right, if you pass your data from an array using foreach.

Comment: Where the $rows came from? Show us your DB request and how you process a DB result to array $rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$chunkedArray  = array_chunk($rows, 3); //productList Array, number of chunks/parts
foreach($chunkedArray as $newRow) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
    foreach ($newRow as $display) {
?>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
             <div class="section-title">
                 <div class="pull-right pr-icon">
                      <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> Top Suppliers 
                 </div>
                 <div class="main-title">
                      <b>  Selected Products</b>
                 </div>
                 <div class="sub-title">
                     Source the latest items
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                      <img src="<?php echo 'data:image;base64,'.$display->image; ?>" class="img-responsive image product-item" />
                      <div class="product-description">
                         <p class="text-center"><?php echo $display->name; ?></p>
                         <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/itemcontroller/itemFetch?id=<?php echo $display->name; ?>"><p class="desc-btn">VIEW</p></a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div> 
         </div>  
    <?php
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
    ?>
```

`array_chunk` would do the work..
know more on `array_chunk` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_chunk.asp)

Comment: @Rahul: Does this mean that your problem has been solved? If so, you should consider [accepting the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).